# 90s picture book from my childhood with illustrative big cats (tigers, lions) in space with colorful planets and galaxies

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story

Likely from the late 80s/early 90s. All I can remember are just a few pages, no title. It was definitely for kids. I think there may have been a few words on every page, but it was mostly these big illustrations of like big wild cats (maybe other animals) mixed in with illustrations of outer space. There were lots of big colorful planets, starts, and galaxies.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what books you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).